# Connect cassandra through ppk file and username

Tags: java, linux, cassandra

I have a ppk file and username "x@domain.com", which I use to connect to Apache cassandra through putty from my windows system. What code snippet can be used in java using datastax to connect the same.I could see the IP of cassandra system from putty terminal.

```
 package com.cassandra.tutorial;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class CassConnector {
private static Cluster cluster;
private static Session session;

public static Cluster connect(String node)
{
    return cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build();
    }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    cluster=connect("172.31.yy.xx");
    session=cluster.connect("core");
    session.execute("USE core");
    session.close();
    cluster.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PPK file is used by Putty to connect to host with Cassandra via SSH protocol.

You can connect to Cassandra itself only by using username & password configured inside it. See [corresponding part of Cassandra's documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#authentication) on how to enable & configure password-based authentication.

After you configure it, you just need to add the call of `withCredentials` function into your cluster building chain, and pass username & password to it.